# Replace character returned in Grafana Logs panel

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have logs gathered from Grafana Loki. They have a control character `\u0001` that I want to use a Grafana `regexp` or `pattern` to replace with a   whitespace.

The Grafana Logs panel looks like this:

[image: Logs Panel]

I can add an expression to the query like this

[image: expressions]

What should I use here to replace the `\u0001` characters? Thanks